# eventContext leaking with LitElement

Tags: memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, custom-element, lit-element, lit-html

I'm using lit-element (v2.3.1) & lit-html (v1.2.1) and having a memory leak where as a result of rendering, detached DOM nodes are not cleaned by GC and the only retainers shown for them by Chrome DevTools are WeakMaps used internally by lit-html to keep track of parts:

[image]

This doesn't happen with all renders, but I have not found a difference between the templates/renders that do and do not leak. Seems almost random. But maybe I'm missing something obvious here, would be glad to hear any suggestions regarding this.

Comment: Maybe they are elements where you have placed an event listener?

Comment: Parents are only listening to events on children by using lit-html's @ syntax to attach the listeners, there are no listeners attached by me through addEventListener or on-. From what I understand about lit-html, detaching parents from DOM should have been enough to allow GC to collect the parents and children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, there is [a known issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/issues/848) with one of the web components I'm using (mwc-ripple) where it attaches event listeners to window and fails to remove them, thus, the browser keeps in memory the whole tree containing the element leading to the memory leak described.